# SOS! Cannot boot Ubuntu, emergency mode, pr.cpu0._pdc error

Tags: boot, acpi

I just powered on my laptop, it said checkdisk is needed, but checkdisk stopped after about 30% and went into first picture's screen.
After ctl -xb I faced several errors as in next pictures.

I was running ubuntu 20.04, and tried installing 21.20 but I face the same error. looks like a firmware or efi problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As you running Ubuntu 20.04 or 21.04? Have there been any firmware updates applied lately? 

Comment: I am running 21.04, and some firmware updates might have been there recently. Looks like EFI problems? I am completely unfamiliar with these kinds of things